# Can show the toast but cant startActivity

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am using an adapter class to populate my listview, but each item in my listview has two textviews to whom I wanna setOnClick listener. So I set it in adapter class and it works fine when I try to show the toast.

But the problem is I cant startActivity within OnClickListener. The app crashes. Please help or suggest an alternate way to achieve the same.
The activity is already mentioned in Manifest.

**This Is My Code:-**

```
public class Adapter_NearMe_TyreWorx extends ArrayAdapter<List_NearMe> implements View.OnClickListener {
    ArrayList<List_NearMe> arraylist;



    private Context context;
    private List<List`enter code here`_NearMe> list;
    public Adapter_NearMe_TyreWorx(Context context, int resource, List<List_NearMe> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.List = objects;
        arraylist = new ArrayList<List_NearMe>();
        arraylist.addAll(List);

    }
    TextView Btn_Call;
     String Fac_landmark;
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.canvas_two, parent, false);
        List_NearMe list= list.get(position);

        String Fac_name=list.getName();
         Fac_landmark=list.getLandmark();

        String Fac_gMap=list.getgMap();
        String Fac_contact=list.getContact();

        TextView distance=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fac_distance);
        TextView Fac_Name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fac_name);
        TextView Fac_Address=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fac_address);
         Btn_Call=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        TextView Btn_Go=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_go);

        Btn_Go.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }



    public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Toast text",LENGTH.SHORT).show(); //working toast code



        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SampleActivity.class);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post logcat after the crash? And the code of SampleActivity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a Intent flag to pass a Intent from a Non - Activity class `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` adding this flag in intent will work fine try to pass your Intent like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SampleActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SampleActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SampleActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

call the method on the context which you are setting in the constructor of the adapter.

as `startActivity()` can only be started from the method which in the context of the application, as your adapter is not there you would have to reference the `context` which you have provided at the `constructor` of your adapter class

Answer (score 0):

replace `getContext()` with context.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```